How do I view the category to which a post was saved without visiting the saves list?
Whenever I come across a question while browsing the site and discover that it had already been saved and I want to know to what category I had saved it, how do I do this without checking all my saves manually? This gets quite tedious when I have a lot of posts saved.

We can't. Better change this into a feature request asking to add this feature, same way the other one asks to see private notes directly in the same page.

@ShadowWizard Seeing the name of the list is already included in the other feature request.

@ElementsInSpace ah, so technically it's a duplicate, following MSE "unwritten rules". However won't use my hammer for that.

@ShadowWizard This is a support question, the other post is a feature request.

@ShadowWizard why not? I am thinking of closing my question as a duplicate since a question about the same topic has already been asked, albeit it's a feature request and mine is a support one.

@ElementsInSpace well, when the answer to support question is a plain "No", it essentially becomes "OK, so since it is not possible, I'd like this to become possible" i.e. it's pretty much the same.

@ShadowWizard In 6–8 years (or however long it takes), when the feature request is implemented, that post will be status-complete and essentially obsolete/historical.  This post will need a new answer (“Yes”).

Currently, there is no way to see which list a saved post is in — other than by finding that post in the Saves tab on your profile page.
When Bookmarks evolved into Saves in 2022 there were a lot of bugs reported and improvements suggested.  Some of these got fixed, but a there are still a lot that were seemingly forgotten, or just deprioritised.
I made a feature request which asks for the private notes and the name of the list to be shown on the posts that they have been applied to:  See private notes on saved posts
